# diiimonn/yii2-widget-checkbox-multiple need to implement

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-widget

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'template_id')->widget(CheckboxMultiple::className(), [
  'dataAttribute' => 'template_id',
  scriptOptions' => [450=>'abc',452=>'xyz'],
 'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select ...'),
]) ?>
```

I try to implement this => https://github.com/diiimonn/yii2-widget-checkbox-multiple

but i am not getting the result.
When I have done code I am getting blank page.

What is the mistake here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any errors in js console? I think that problem seems to be with assets bundle of CheckboxMultiple widgets. There are missing depends property for JQuery Assets. Try to register jQuery manually before render widget. `dataAttribute` property also seems to be unknown in latest version of this widget... This works for me:

```
$this->registerAssetBundle(yii\web\JqueryAsset::className());

echo $form->field($model, 'templates')->widget(CheckboxMultiple::className(), [
    'attributeLabel' => 'templates',
    'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select ...'),
    'ajax' => [
        'url' => Url::toRoute(['/site/templates']),
    ],
]);
```

Where templates attribute is relation in model, like this:

```
public function getTemplates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TemplateModel::className(), ['owner_id' => 'id']);
}
```

and in SiteController action templates:

```
public function actionTemplates()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    $json = new \stdClass();
    $query = new Query();
    $query->select([
        'id' => 'id',
        'text' => 'name'
    ]);
    $query->from(TemplateModel::tableName());
    if ($search = Yii::$app->request->post('search', '')) {
        $query->where(['like', 'name', $search]);
    }
    $query->orderBy([
        'name' => SORT_ASC
    ]);
    if ($itemsId = Yii::$app->request->post('itemsId', [])) {
        $query->andWhere(['not in', 'id', $itemsId]);
    }
    $query->limit(20);
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $data = $command->queryAll();
    $json->results = array_values($data);

    return $json;
}
```

In this example I use table `templates` with columns: `id`, `name` and `owner_id`.
You should modify above script to yours names of models and attributes.

Comment: I will try this on Monday

Comment: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/physicshs/admin/template-group/add"

Comment: This error is displayed in js console or in view page? Did you set ajax url to this widget? And what is displayd if you manually run localhost/physicshs/admin/template-group/add ?

Comment: in a console and I have no any ajax url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139129/discussion-between-knowledge-and-marcin-gordel).